# Constant FPDF_VERSION already defined - Ayuda

Tags: php

Estoy armando un PDF con FPDI y autoprint pero cuando corro el sistema me sale esto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la linea 10

```
define('FPDF_VERSION','1.81');
```

Comment: y si eliminas esa linea?

Comment: El problema no está en esa línea, si no que es el síntoma de un problema anterior. ¿Podrías agregar en tu pregunta cómo cargas las librerías `fpdf` y `fpdi`?